# How do i make toString() tail recursive in scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm taking the scala course on coursera , and i'm trying out the things being taught there. So now i come across this list they call "ConsList" ? and i am trying to give it a tail-recursive toString() method. I suppose i have to keep something like an accumulator , but i'm not sure how to do that either. Any help will be much appreciated.

here's what i'v tried :

```
/** a non-empty element/node of the list */
class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = false;
  override def toString() = 
    if(tail.isEmpty) "{" + head + "}"
    else "{" + head + tail + "}"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common way of implementing accumulator pattern in scala is through inner method:

```
def stringifyList[T](xs: List[T]) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def inner(cnt: List[T], acc: String): String = {
    if (cnt.isEmpty) acc
    else inner(cnt.tail, acc + cnt.head)
  }
  inner(xs, "")
}
```

If you take a look you'll see that logic behind tailrec functions very similar to while loop, in which it's actually is desugared by scala compiler.

Algorithm is also very simple, like in any recursive function you need some stop point (when list is empty), then you just return you accumulator (in this case a string). In either case you are calling function again with new iteration (return list tail and put head into the accumulator).

**Remember** that in Scala you must provide explicit result type for recursive function (in this case `String`)

Comment: Your answer really helps ! thanks a lot :) However, any reason you're using `xs` as list name ? i found martin odersky also doing the same thing in the videos , is this a naming convention ?

Comment: @SomjitNag yep, this comes from list and very common in FP, just means X'es, many X, where X is just a common name for a variable (for example in math functions it's used very often)